# how to determine if a POINT is inside the area of a button

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mfc

how to determine  if a POINT is inside the area of a button? 
the POINT is in screen coordinates , and I have the handle of the window in which the button is and the handle of the button. 
I tried ::ScreenToClient(okBtnH , &tempPosition) where okBtnH is the handle of the button and the tempPosition is a POINT structure in screen coordinates. but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to do this except manual calculation of the screen position of the button and then compare it with the POINT str ?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"

Comment: ::ScreenToClient return false and GetLastError returns Error 1400. Invalid Windows Handle

Comment: Error 1400 corresponds to 'ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE', you could post some code to show how you are using the function or take another look at how you are using your window handle.

Comment: here is my code: HWND okBtnH; TopWindow * guiWindow;  guiWindow = new TopWindow(NULL);    guiWindow->Create(TopWindow::IDD , NULL); guiWindow->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);   HWND okBtnH = ::GetDlgItem(guiWindow->m_hWnd,IDOK);  POINT tempPosition = popsition;
 if (!::ScreenToClient(okBtnH , &tempPosition)){DWORD i = ::GetLastError();}

Comment: don't you just send the window a hit test message?

Comment: sorry about the question it rely was an invalid handle. when I initialize it i do something like this "HWND okBtnH = ::GetDlgItem(guiWindow->m_hWnd,IDOK);" which creates a new variable , not writing to the member one. Thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `okBtnH` is a **handle** for the button control, and not just its ID? If `ScreenToClient` is failing with "Invalid Handle" then your handle is likely invalid.

Comment: here is how I obtain it HWND okBtnH = ::GetDlgItem(guiWindow->m_hWnd,IDOK);  and on msdn is says that GetDlgItem return NULL if it fails and if it return something then it a valid handle. So maybe the question is more like does ScreenToClient also works for buttons and other controls?

Comment: Yes, `ScreenToClient` works for buttons and other controls --- anything with a valid `HWND`. If you have nested frames and views then your button might also not be a direct child of the window you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MFC then you can just call the member function ScreenToClient. Why do you call the global version and are you sure the handle is the buttons handle?

Comment: sorry about the question it rely was an invalid handle. when I initialize it i do something like this "HWND okBtnH = ::GetDlgItem(guiWindow->m_hWnd,IDOK);" which creates a new variable , not writing to the member one. Thanks;

Comment: @ghet: you should add this to the original question (as a matter of fact, you should also add the code in the question's comment as part of the question). Until I got to reading this comment I did not understand why you had accepted Anthony's answer. Just click on the *edit* option in the question and add first the code, which you can properly format selecting it and using the *{}* button, and then what was the actual issue.